# why console print in reverse order than load script?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, requirejs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to use require js and angular js  simultaneously .But I am getting reverse console out put as compare to load script.in other words When I run and check my network and console both are opposite why ?Example    console.log("login controller js start") print first and it loaded at last in dom why ?   console.log("bootstrap  js end") loaded at first but print at end of console.Please refer images

here is plunker 
http://plnkr.co/edit/5bOh622bnlDAyR0BGXOH?p=preview

```
/*global define, console */

define(function () {
    'use strict';
    console.log("login controller js start")
    function ctrl($scope, $state) {

        $scope.login = function () {
           alert("--")
        };

    }

    ctrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$state'];
     console.log("login controller js end")
    console.log(ctrl);
    return ctrl;

});
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use requireJS. So requireJS will load the modules in the order of your requireJS dependencies configuration and initialize first the module without dependencies.

For example you have 3 modules with the following dependencies:

> app -> angular -> jquery

In your application you define a dependency to the module **app**. requireJS will resolve the dependencies to **angular** and **jquery**. But of course it has to initialize the modules in reverse order.